# spring boot app referencing the jsp pages with hard coded full path names

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp, jar

We have our web-java project structured in the following way (showing only the JSP layout):

```
src/main:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  staff  102 Mar 14 15:33 java
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  staff  374 Mar 14 15:33 resources
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  staff  102 Mar 14 15:33 webapp

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  20 root  staff  680 Mar 14 15:33 jsp
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.cloudwick.datastax.retail</groupId>
    <artifactId>CwkDatastaxRetail</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>CwkDatastaxRetail</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-solr</artifactId>

        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tictactec</groupId>
            <artifactId>ta-lib</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Java Mail API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>

        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka_2.9.2</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.1.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
      <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

when i build the Jar with mvn clean package and run the Jar locally with java -jar target/MyApp.jar the app runs perfectly with all the JSP pages. But if i deploy the Jar to a remote machine and run java -jar MyApp.jar the app does not display any JSP pages. I checked the Jar to see the files included and found that the JSP pages were not included. I changed my pom.xml and added to include the webapp folder in the resources as shown below:

```
<project>
 ...
 <build>
   ...
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>src/main/java</directory>
     </resource>
     <resource>
       <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
     </resource>
     <resource>
       <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
   ...
 </build>
 ...
</project>
```

And again i packaged my Jar and deployed to remote machine. But still it does not run the JSP pages. And another interesting thing is that the Jar run locally only from the project directory runs successfully and the if run from any other directory locally does not run the JSP pages or it does not find the JSP pages even if its included in the JAR. Here is my application.properties file:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

I want to build the JAR and successfully deploy it to the remote system without having any JSP issues.

Comment: Have a look at the docs (the very last section "JSP limitations" - it also provides a link to a sample application) http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Comment: I am a complete Spring Boot noob, so I am wondering what is the recommended way to do remote deployments?  Is it building a war file for deployment to an application server?  Or does it have anything like the Play Web Framework with a "bring your own container" model?